# 12.0 can't be identified as double nor int or numeric in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this problem with dart. I created a simple calculator. If the result if a calculation is equal to, for example, -12.9 or 12.9. The app gives the correct answer and no error. But, if the answer given is 12.0 or -12.0, the app crashes. Why is that? I created a function to check if the string is an int or a double. It returns false.

```js
bool isDouble(String number) {
  try {
    num n = num.parse(number);
    if (n % 1 == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

For the numeric, I used the isNumeric function in dart. Please help me.

Comment: The above function *will* return `false`, because `12.0 % 1` equals `0`. Also, it doesn’t crash.

Comment: hmm i'm really off right now, im very confused. thank you, will try to debug it more.

Comment: oh on the side note, is there a way to remove the decimal values of a double?

Answer (score 1):

As Riwen mentioned, any whole number % 1 is 0, even if it's a float. You can check the type of a variable with .runtimeType. I think when you parse the string to num, it automatically converts whole numbers to int, so you cant just check if runtimeType == "double". Also, to remove decimal values, you can just use .floor(), which will round down and convert the variable to an int.

This function seems to work:

```
bool isDouble(String number) {
  if (int.tryParse(number) == null){
    if (double.parse(number).isFinite) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: i'll try this, thank you so much. I will update you